# PHP: working with functions storing array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a

```
function displayErr(){
    $err[] = "You have an error";
}
```

later in my code

```
if($bla==false) { displayErr(); }
if(!empty($err)) { echo print_r($err); }
```

I don't get anything, can't I call a function that adds on `$err` and then check it later?

Comment: I'd recommend refactoring into an error logging class.

Comment: I suggest to rename your function. `displayErr` is not displaying the errors at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$err` is only visible in the scope of your `displayErr()` function. You need to *pass* it, or its values, around. A couple of options:

1. Return the error message and append to `$err` within the calling scope

   ```
   function displayErr() {
       return "You have an error";
   }

   $err = array();
   if($bla==false) { $err[] = displayErr(); }
   if(!empty($err)) { print_r($err); }
   ```
2. Use `global`

   ```
   function displayErr() {
       global $err;
       $err[] = "You have an error";
   }

   $err = array();
   if($bla==false) { displayErr(); }
   if(!empty($err)) { print_r($err); }
   ```

Also, `print_r()` outputs stuff by itself, you don't need to `echo print_r()`.

Comment: thank you, is this the same with if i should check for $_SESSION inside a function?

Comment: @Karem: No, `$_SESSION` is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) which means you don't need to do `global $_SESSION;`.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `$err` is is only visible within the function `displayErr()`. What you want is to access a global variable within the function. To do this, you need to import it using the `global` keyword, as the following example shows:

```
function displayErr(){
    global $err;
    $err[] = "You have an error";
}
```

For more information regarding variable scope, see this link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

`$err` is only available in your `displayErr` function.

You need to add a `global` statement. Like this: `displayErr() {global $err; ... }`

This is called variable scoping, and you can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `global` keyword to store your variable as global:

```
function displayErr()
{ 
global $err;
$err = "You have an error"; 
}

[...]

global $err;
if($bla==false) { displayErr(); } if(!empty($err)) { echo print_r($err); }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple error handling class example:

```
class ErrorHandler()
{
    private $errors = array();

    public function add_error($error = 'You have an error')
    {
        $this->errors[] = $error;
    }

    public function get_errors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function print_errors()
    {
        print_r($this->errors);
    }
}

$errorhandler = new ErrorHandler;
if($bla==false) $errorhandler->add_error('Variable bla is not set!');
if($bla=='unknown error') $errorhandler->add_error();

$errors = $errorhandler->get_errors();
if($errors) print_r($errors); // or
if($errors) $errorhandler->print_errors();
```